Artifacts when using Weighted normals - Solved
I got these artifacts in the corners (incorrect normals ?) every time I make topology like that. It's a low poly mesh with Weighted Normals modifier. If I export the mesh to Zbrush, save as fbx and import back to Blender the problem is gone (3rd picture). What is the problem here ?

Mesh processed through Zbrush

Initial Mesh

I found the difference between objects. The object put through Zbrush has scale 0.01. When I run Apply Transforms it breaks and becomes like the "blender" object. I add a file where two objects are placed together.



Hello and welcome. Can you share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

I share both meshes separately. When I put first mesh into second file, the first mesh also become bad. I also noticed that Zbrush mesh have Smooth normals greyed out. Sorry, don't have time for now to look more into this by myself.

I think you need to go to the object data panel (little green triangle on the right with a mesh selected) and go to Geometry Data >Clear Custom Split Normals after you import from ZBrush. Each software has it's own way it calculate split normals and stores that data in the FBX. Most times this will get weird if you manipulate normals in one packages then try to manipulate again after moving between another software.

Yes, mesh put through Zbrush have custom normals data, but clearing it doesn't add artifacts, the mesh is still good.

Also the problem is persistent in Unity and Substance, please help, don't understand what's the matter.

Ok, I solved my own problem. To fix this you need to set Threshold parameter in Weighted Normal modifier to 0 (default value is 0.01). And in general, if you encounter a problem like this one, you play with Threshold parameter.

As far as I understand it, Weighted Normals is based on the geometry. It sort of interpolates the normals between vertices. This means you can control the normals with the geometry :

I'm getting the same issue as you on the left, there isn't enough geometry.
You can add Loop Cuts with Ctrl+R. It should work easily with your geometry.

You should have bevels on the cube for it to look good, your answer is unrelated.

I don't understand what you mean. The way Weighted Normals work is unrelated to your question ? Or maybe I'm misunderstanding Weighted Normals, totally possible.

This is a technique used in lowpoly 3d where you are adding a bevels to hard edges and then a Weighted Normals so your object look "highpoly". Try to add bevels to the cube and you will understand.

You could add only 2 loopcuts, but I understand that it can be already too much for your case.
